# Why does iron have an abnormally high ionization energy?

Tags: electronic-configuration, transition-metals, ionization-energy

Along a period the ionization energy should increase because the atomic number is increasing, but there is negligible increase in shielding. However, $\mathrm{IE}_\ce{Mn} < \mathrm{IE}_\ce{Fe} > \mathrm{IE}_\ce{Co} > \mathrm{IE}_\ce{Cu}$, so why does iron have such a high ionization energy?

I've considered that iron has a $\mathrm{4s^2 3d^6}$ configuration that goes to a $\mathrm{4s^1 3d^6}$ configuration upon ionization, while $\ce{Co}$ has a $\mathrm{4s^2 3d^7}$ that goes to $\mathrm{4s^0 3d^8}$ configuration, $\ce{Ni}$ has a $\mathrm{4s^2 3d^8}$ that goes to a $\mathrm{4s^0 3d^9}$ configuration and $\ce{Cu}$ has a $\mathrm{4s^2 3d^9}$ that goes to a $\mathrm{4s^0 3d^{10}}$ configuration (Lang, J. Chem. Ed., 2003).  In the Long paper, the authors explain the increase of IE at iron is due to "electronic structure" and I would like to know exactly what about the electronic structure it is that causes iron to have a high IE than expected based on a general periodic trend.

I was thinking that adding an electron to the $\mathrm{3d}$ orbitals might be energetically favorable enough to lower the ionization energy of $\ce{Ni}$, $\ce{Co}$ and $\ce{Cu}$, so rather than iron having a high ionization energy the surround metals just have a low ionization energy because the ion is stabilized by having another $\mathrm{d}$-electron added? Does that sound reasonable?

Another thing I was thinking was that iron is the first transition metal to have a paired $\mathrm{d}$-electron, could that effect the shielding and increase the ionization energy?

Comment: The first ionization energy of cobalt is only 0.3% lower than that of iron. So I wouldn't say that iron has an abnormal high ionization energy.

Comment: @aventurin I mean "abnormal" in that it defies a general periodic trend, the magnitude itself is not abnormal

Answer (score -1):

"I mean "abnormal" in that it defines a general trend" makes no sense to me at all. Did you mean "defies"?  Take a look at the chart here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy.
By my count, for the s-block elements the "trend" always holds.  For the p-block elements, it holds in 5/6ths of the cases. And for the d-block, I can't tell from the chart, but claiming it is increasing for them seems agross exaggeration to me; I'd say they might have a very slight tendency to increase, but they're so close to being flat-lined, that it seems to be not a useful claim. If you count the exceptions to the rule, and you expect your "rules" to hold at least 90% to 95% of the time (this isn't the Social Sciences, after all), then it is a just plain lousy rule. Nothing unusual about that: I think the Periodic Table is best when used to "predict" Atomic Number (they increase moving right and down, without exception), and so untrustworthy with the other periodic trends as to *not* be something in my "mental toolbox". Use it at your own peril. (The at. no. "trend" was a joke, of course)

Comment: I did mean "defies", I apologize for the confusion and I fixed my mistake.  I know the trend is not a rule, like all other trends, but this is still something that people research and have published papers about.  I'm unclear on an aspect  of a peer-reviewed paper, and I would like an answer, I don't see why that's a problem.

Comment: Could you please add some formatting, especially paragraph breaks to your answer? As it is, it is too time-consuming for me to read thus I am abstaining from voting.