Why is the first ionization energy of Fe greater than Mn
I looked at the ionization energy of the 3D series and saw that the IE of Fe is greater than Mn as in this diagram:

As common logic would dictate in Mn you are breaking a very stable configuration hence it would be greater than Fe, what is the reason (If there is one) behind this.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81773/why-does-iron-have-an-abnormally-high-ionization-energy

@Mithoron that doesn't really answer OP questions. In fact, it compares it oppositely

@ChemLover68 Well, it seems fine for OP...

In transition metals, 4s have the highest orbital energy (A phenomenon called d orbital collapse means that 3d has lower energy than 4s in transition metals and the p-block when it is filled). So 1st ionization energy is from the 4s orbital as you ionize from the highest energy orbital. Both has same 4s configuration but iron has greater effective nuclear charge as it has more protons so electrons are more attracted to the nucleus. So it has greater 1st and 2nd ionization energy.
However, you are in some aspect correct. The 3rd ionization energy (removal from 3d orbital) of manganese is greater than iron due to the stability of manganese 3d electron configuration.
